# Activemerchant ogone => Merchant not active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I'm trying to implement a ogone test account in my rails development application, but I keep getting the error message 'Merchant not active'
After some investigation I believe it has something to do with the SHA encoding?
Problem is I don't really get how this works, Ogone has multple SHA parameters to fill out and I haven't found a way in activemerchant to put it in there.
Someone with some experience in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the `Merchant not active` error is because your account is not configured to be able to use Direct Link or several other options. To activate this you should get a higher subscription or contact their support and ask them to activate it for you.

As for SHA, you need to configure a secret passphrase by which you separate the parameters you're sending. For instance:

```
Passphrase:  ogonepass123
Post variables:  CN=JohnDoeogonepass123AMOUNT=1000ogonepass123CURRENCY=EURogonepass123PSPID=MyPSPID
```

Eventually you Hash your post variables to SHA-1 and add that key to your post parameters as

```
....ogonepass123SHASIGN=<40-characters-SHA-key>
```

This way you secure your data and make sure nobody can tamper with those variables.

Also make sure that when you get a response from Ogone you re-form a SHA hash using the parameters they've send you and you then compare this own-formed SHA hash with the one sent to you by Ogone. If these two match you can be sure that the parameters have not been messed with.

Hope this helps you or others who come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

to work with Ogone Direct Link with an account created after Mai 10, 2010 you will need this patches : https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/pull/85
(This also works with accounts created before this date.)

This will also give you more details on the aliases usage, fix some issues with new updates from Ogone, ... make sure to read the inline doc within the ogone gateway code : https://github.com/ZenCocoon/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/ogone.rb

As of today, the SHA1 is supported and to be used.